# Get count of each value in table column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I have a table that has a 'Status' column in it.  There are five possible statuses: Submitted, In Progress, Deleted, Implemented, Not Implemented.

I'm trying to figure out to write a SQL Statement that will return the count of each of these statuses but my code is either returning the number statuses, or the count of a specific status.  Here's what I was working with:

```
SELECT     COUNT(ServiceAreaID) AS ServiceArea
FROM         Suggestions
WHERE     (ServiceAreaID = 6)
```

or this one

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT ServiceAreaID) AS ServiceArea
FROM         Suggestions
```

Comment: Do you want to know how many times each `ServiceAreaID` appears in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one:

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Suggestions
WHERE ServiceAreaID = 6
GROUP BY Status;
```

For all:

```
SELECT ServiceAreaID, Status, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Suggestions
GROUP BY ServiceAreaID, Status;
```

Comment: +1 because you didn't get the accept, and you deserved it. I hope this provides some consolation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select ServiceAreaID,count(*),status
from suggestion
group by status,suggestion;
```

Comment: This query seems to ignore `ServiceAreaID` altogether.

Comment: Unfortunately this syntax doesn't work. You either need to group by ServiceAreaID or remove it from the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ServiceAreaID, COUNT(*) AS ServiceArea
FROM Suggestions
GROUP BY ServiceAreaID
```

That should give you a count of each service area id.  Replace the service area id in the group by with whatever your status is(below includes a status column seperate from serviceAreaID if that is what is needed).

```
 SELECT ServiceAreaID, status, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM Suggestions
    GROUP BY ServiceAreaID, status
```

Comment: Where is the `status` column?

Comment: I assumed the status column was `serviceAreaID` from his code examples.  Hence my comment that he can replace that with the status column if it is different(only can use the information the OP gave me)

Comment: By reading the question I determined there was both a `Status` and `ServiceAreaID` column.

Comment: Yea I did at first too, but then none of his code examples referenced it so I thought the status he was referring to was also the `serviceAreaID`  His code examples never reference a status so I guess I was confused as to where it came in to play(as he seems to want the count of the `serviceAreaID` in his examples

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! I am unfamiliar with the GROUP BY function but doing some reading now.

Comment: @negzero7: Aaron Bertrand deserves the accept here. He gave you the correct answer first.

Comment: i agree, Aaron had it in 30 seconds before me

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT ServiceAreaID, COUNT(ServiceAreaID) AS COUNT
FROM Suggestions
GROUP BY ServiceAreaID
```

I didn't see a `Status` column in your SQL examples, but in case there's supposed to be one, the query would be more like this:

**This answer is basically identical to Aaron's, so if this is what you're looking for make sure to mark Aaron as the answer.**

```
SELECT ServiceAreaID, Status, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM Suggestions
GROUP BY ServiceAreaID, Status
```

Comment: What about the `Status` column?

Comment: I was wondering about that, but I didn't see any references to a status in his examples. I guess it wouldn't hurt to add it though.